# What is the order of $\mathrm{Z}(x)-\pi(x)?$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, distribution-of-primes

Consider the offset logarithmic integral which approximates the number of primes up to a given $x$ quite well $$ \mathrm{Li}(x)=\int_2^x\frac{1}{\log t}~dt$$

And consider the alternating series

$$\mathrm{Z}(x)= \sum_{n=2}^x (-1)^{n+1}e^{\sin\big(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\log n}\big)} $$

$\mathrm{Z}(x)$ remarkably stays close to $\mathrm{Li}(x)$ and is at least asymptotic to $\mathrm{Li}(x)$ from what I can tell. For example I tested this at $x=10^8$ the difference between the two is only about $4$ with $\mathrm{Z}(x)$ slightly less than the offset logarithmic integral.

> What is the order of $\mathrm{Z}(x)-\pi(x)?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $\sin z=z+O(z)$ and $e^z=1+z+\frac12z^2+O(z^3)$ as $z\to0$,
so we have

\begin{aligned}
Z(x)
&=\sum_{2\le n\le x}(-1)^{n+1}e^{(-1)^{n+1}/\log n+O(1/\log^3n)} \\
&=\sum_{2\le n\le x}(-1)^{n+1}\left[1+{(-1)^{n+1}\over\log n}+{1\over2\log^2n}+O\left(1\over\log^3n\right)\right] \\
&=\sum_{2\le n\le x}{1\over\log n}+\sum_{2\le n\le x}(-1)^{n+1}+\frac12\sum_{2\le n\le x}{(-1)^{n+1}\over\log^2n}+O\left(\sum_{2\le n\le x}{1\over\log^3n}\right).
\end{aligned}

Notice that the second sum is bounded, the third sum converges, and

$$
\sum_{2\le n\le x}{1\over\log^3n}\le\sum_{2\le n\le\sqrt x}{1\over\log^32}+\sum_{\sqrt x<n\le x}{1\over\log^3\sqrt x}=O\left(x\over\log^3x\right),
$$

so we have

$$
Z(x)=\sum_{2\le n\le x}{1\over\log n}+O\left(x\over\log^3x\right).\tag1
$$

It can be proven that the remaining summation has bounded difference from $\operatorname{Li}(x)$, so we conclude that

$$
Z(x)-\operatorname{Li}(x)=O\left(x\over\log^3x\right).\tag2
$$

Although (2) only provides an O-bound, if we expand more terms from $\sin z$ and $e^z$, it is pretty likely that one will conclude the true order of error is $x/(\log x)^A$ for some fixed $A\ge3$, which is much worse than the order of $\pi(x)-\operatorname{Li}(x)$:

$$
\pi(x)-\operatorname{Li}(x)=O(xe^{-(\log x)^B})
$$

for some $0<B<1$.